# How do I create an extended generic return type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

Just wondering if something like this is possible and if so what is the proper syntax:

```
 export interface IElement {...}

 export interface X {
     one<T>(name: string, id: string): T extends IElement;
     two<T>(name: string, id: string): Observable<T extends IElement>;
     three<T>(name: string, id: string): Observable<Array<T extends IElement>>;
 }
```

Basically I want to return an object that has all the properties of the object the consumer specifies in the method call with all the methods/props of another Interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intersection Types

```
interface IElement { }

interface X {
    one<T>(name: string, id: string): T & IElement;
    two<T>(name: string, id: string): Observable<T & IElement>;
    three<T>(name: string, id: string): Observable<Array<T & IElement>>;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible. Just put the `extends` constraint inside the generic signature:

```
export interface IElement {}

export interface X {
    one<T extends IElement>(name: string, id: string): T;
    two<T extends IElement>(name: string, id: string): Observable<T>;
    three<T extends IElement>(name: string, id: string): Observable<Array<T>>;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that saying that the T the consumer is passing into the function already implements IElement? My intent is to add IElement to T and return it.

Comment: For this constraint, to be valid T needs to implement IElement interface. Was not that what you wanted?

Comment: Nope: Given object X I want to return object X + added properties/methods(IElement) and get intellisense on them... Basically I only want to constrain/define the return type